# Mapping $\Re(z) > 1$ Across The Complex Plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, mapping-class-group

**Question:** Map $\Re(z) > 1$ under $f(z) = z^2 + 2z + 1$

**What I've Tried:**
Using algebraic manipulation, I've gotten the equations:

$(w)^2 - 1 = z$ and by extension, $(u + iv)^{1/2} -1  = x + iy$  (Assuming $w = u+iv$ and $z=x+iy$)

I tried expanding this and found that:

$$u = x^2+y^2+2x+1 \;\text{ and }\; v = 2xy + 2y$$

Taking $x$ as $1$ (since $\Re(z)$ represents the half plane beginning at $x = 1$), I found:
$4y = v$
$y= (u-3)^{1/2}$

I'm not really certain where to go from here.  Should I have used polar coordinates?  Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help

Comment: where does $(w)^2-1=z$ comes from?

Comment: @Isabella I ended up figuring this one out (very simple computation towards the end), but the (w^2) -1 = z comes from the first equation.  f(z) = z^2 + 2x + 1 can be simplified to (z+1)^2.  If f(z) = w, then w = (z+1)^2

Comment: $w=(z+1)^2\implies w^2=z+1$ ?